# R functions re-usability

Tags: aggregate

I'm trying to use the same block of code to analyze for 3 different years.

```
year = c("Year.2006", "Year.2016", "Year.2031")

    for(x in year){
      print(x)
      print(new_Data$x)
      Tot_data <- setNames(aggregate(new_Data$x, by=list(State = new_Data$State), FUN=sum), c("state","total"))
      children_data <- new_Data[new_Data$Age_num <= 15,]
      ...}
```

Trying to replace the instances of year in the above code to use in function. How should I pass the years in aggregate?

dput(head(new_Data))

```
 structure(list(Age = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), State = c("NSW", 
"Vic", "QLD", "SA", "WA", "Tas"), X2006 = c("6,024", "1255", 
"5,324", "1007", "2,391", "679"), X2016 = c("6,597", "1,480", 
"5,295", "986", "2,300", "644"), X2031 = c("8,517", "2,122", 
"7,205", "1,254", "2,767", "808"), Age_num = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), Year.2006 = c(6024, 1255, 5324, 1007, 2391, 679), Year.2016 = c(6597, 
1480, 5295, 986, 2300, 644), Year.2031 = c(8517, 2122, 7205, 
1254, 2767, 808)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @RonakShah Noted. Edited.

Comment: In your code above there is `combined_df$x` for calculation of `growth_rate` but you don't have `x` column in your data anywhere. From where that column is coming or should that be something else?

Comment: Edited it's in the code give. Just the previous step before combined_df$x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested this due to lack of reproducible example but you can run `aggregate` function by passing a `formula` object. Create a formula object using `reformulate` by passing `year` as character value and use `[[` to extract a column value as vector.

```
aggregated_data <- function(new_data, year) {
  Tot_data <- setNames(aggregate(reformulate('State', year), new_data, sum), c("state","total"))
  children_2016_data <- new_data[new_data$Age_num <= 15,]
  total_sum_by_state <- aggregate(reformulate('State', year), children_2016_data, sum)
  combined_df = cbind(total_sum_by_state,Tot_data)
  growth_rate <- combined_df
  growth_rate$percentage <- growth_rate[[year]]/growth_rate$total * 100
  max_child_pop_2016_state <- as.character(growth_rate$State[which.max(growth_rate$percentage)])
  max_child_pop_2016_percentage <- as.character(growth_rate$percentage[which.max(growth_rate$percentage)])
  sprintf("The regions with maximum children population in the %s is %s with percentage as %s",year, max_child_pop_2016_state, max_child_pop_2016_percentage)
}
```

Now run this using `lapply` :

```
year = c("Year.2006", "Year.2016", "Year.2031")
lapply(year, aggregated_data, new_data = new_data)
```

Comment: My datatypes are as follows: State<chr> x<dbl> state<chr> total<dbl>  I'm getting this error: Error in x/total : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: @Newbie Can you add `dput(head(new_data))` ?

Comment: added to the question

Comment: @Newbie Check the updated answer if it works for your data.